# Washing after Haircut and modern day blood letting

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, hair, medicine

What are the rules for Washing after Haircuts and or Shaving and or is there a requirement at all? Also after donating blood is there a requirment to Wash hands and or a blood test and is there a difference between them foe washing meaning are they both similar to Letting blood in Talmudical Times and hence require washing or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Regarding blood-letting, while there
> are those who are accustomed to
> washing their hands after giving blood
> (either to be tested, or for
> donation), Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach
> (cited by the Nishmat Avraham 1 (Orach Chaim) Siman 4 Seif Katan 5)
> believed that "blood-letting" referred
> to a specific medical procedure in
> which the bleeding was beneficial to
> the patient.  Since giving blood, even
> for a blood test, is not for direct
> healing purposes, one is not required
> to wash one's hands.

However it is brought down in sefer Damayich Chayi (pages 55 and 56) in the name of Rav Elyashiv that for donating blood one should wash their hands, and on page 57 he is quoted saying that for a blood test it is not needed (All this is also quoted in Nishmas Avraham noted above).

http://vbm-torah.org/archive/tefila/67-01tefila.htm

Regarding haircuts see this link. http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?PageIndex=88&ClipID=1599

In [Shaalos U'Teshuvos Divrei Chachomim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20287&st=&pgnum=24&hilite=) he brings in the name of HaRav Moshe Feinstein Zatzal that you do not have to wash your hands after shaving.

Comment: Rav Moshe Feinstein's _t'shuva_ on donating blood allows it (under the circumstances he was asked about; CYLOR for practical ruling) (despite the general rule against injuring oneself) in part _because_ (I paraphrase) "there's probably something to that whole bloodletting thing, so donating blood may be good for the donor too". How does that relate to the R'SZA view cited in the answer?

Comment: @msh210 I am confused by your comment. What does Rabbi Moshe Feinstein allow? donating blood? and what does that have to do with what Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach says?

Comment: Yes, donating blood is what he allows (in the case he was asked about). R'SZA is quoted in the answer as saying that since donating blood is not for healing purposes like bloodletting was, one need not wash; but R' Moshe said that bloodletting is (in the case he was asked about) allowed precisely (in part) because it _does_ heal like bloodletting did. So one could argue that, since this is only allowed because it's bloodletting, R'SZA's argument doesn't apply (according to R' Moshe). In any event, that's all nice in theory (or not so nice?), but, as always, CYLOR for practical _halacha_.

Comment: However that is not the only reason why it is allowed according to RMF.

Comment: According to the above, since "Controlled bloodletting is an effective salvage therapy" for hypertensive emergency, such a patient must wash his hands – after the the emergency is over, of course. (Source: Wikipedia – http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertensive_emergency#Treatment)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding shaving or cutting **facial** hair, there was never an obligation to wash afterward.

Comment: We don't see the language of gezeira here (in fact, you won't find this halacha in the Rambam).  So the distinction has to be inherent in the effects of not washing.  Do we find a reasoning by one and not the other?

Comment: Yes. The zei'ah and zohama that exists by hair on the head is worse. If you scratch your head you must wash. If you scratch your beard you do not need to wash.

Comment: Rambam distinguishes the zeia of the face as well as not dangerous.

Comment: @Yahu So it should only apply to the barber not the one receiving a haircut (barbee?).

Comment: @DoubleAA you make a good point in theory; however in reality it is quite unlikely that the hands of the person receiving the haircut will not come in contact with the cut hair, shedded scalp skin, etc. or touch his head at some point during or immediately after the haircut.

Comment: @Yahu I actually generally keep my hands completely under a nice plastic sheet they put over me the whole time.

Comment: @DoubleAA And you don't ever run your hands through your hair before washing it after your haircut?

Comment: @Yahu If I do I should wash; if I don't I shouldn't. That's what follows accd to your argument that the 'din' of 'washing after haircut' is just a common instance of the 'din' of 'washing after touching dirty places such as scalp'.

Comment: @DoubleAA There is no din of washing after touching the scalp in a normal situation. There is a din of washing after scratching the hair, which likely includes the scalp. My assumption is that during or right after the haircut the zohama is loosened so touching is equivalent of giving the haircut.