Does hair have any association with tumah like nails do?
For example, trimming one's hair and leaving the trimmings outside. Does the trimmed hair have a similar status to that of trimmed finger nails in regards to tumah?

Do either of these answer your Q: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65649/halacha-of-hair-disposal
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5109/washing-after-haircut-and-modern-day-blood-letting
?

Fingernails have tumah? Don't recall hearing that

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Mishna Ohalos 3:3 says explicitly:

Every part of a corpse is unclean except the teeth, hair and nails; But when they are joined [to the corpse], they are all unclean.

Gemara Nidah 55a explains:

Everything that is in a corpse transmits impurity, except for the teeth, and the hair, and the nails. This is the halakha only when these items are separated from the body, but when they are attached to the corpse they are all impure. According to Rabbi Yoḥanan teeth should transmit impurity because they are similar to bones, while according to Reish Lakish they should be included in the term “from any.”
Rav Adda bar Ahava said: Only items that are similar to a bone transmit impurity: Just as a bone is an item that was created with him at the time of birth, so too, all items that transmit impurity are those that were created with him, whereas teeth are not present at the time of birth. The Gemara asks: But are there not the cases of hair and nails, which were created with him, and yet the mishna states that they are ritually pure?

While the Gemara continues with its shakla v'tarya, Rambam, Sefer Tahara, Hilkhos Tumas Meis 3:13 gives his psak as in the mishnah:

Every element of a corpse is impure with the exception of the teeth, the hair, and the nails, for they are replaced. While they are attached to the body, they are all impure.
What is implied? When a corpse is outside a house and his hair which is attached to his body is inside, everything in the house becomes impure. Similarly, one who touches hair, teeth, or nails while they are attached to a corpse becomes impure. When the hair of the deceased was ready to be cut or his nails were ready to be trimmed, their halachic status is in doubt because they are prepared to be cut off. Therefore, one who touches them is considered as ritually impure because of the doubt.

In other words, even if a nail is attached to a detached finger or hair attached to a part of a detached head, or a tooth to a jawbone - they transmit tumah upon touching as the limbs themselves transmit tumah. However, detached hair, nails, or teeth do not.
Finally, according to Kitzur Shulchan Arukh 3:9, one should wash one hands after cutting ones hair or one's nails because of spirit of impurity as a result of cutting (as stated in the footnote in the R' Eliyahu Touger translation).
